# [0].outerHTML - why does one need to include '[0]'?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Noob JavaScript/jQuery question...

Why do I need to specify [0] in the following code snippet:

```
$("#select" + " option")[0].outerHTML;
```

Inituitively, I reasoned that omitting [0] would return the outerHTML for all `<option>` tags, but it returns 'undefined'.

To clarify, I know I can use a loop of some kind to iterate through and get the HTML for all the options, I'm just curious to know if there is a syntactic reason why omitting [0] doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It returns a bundle of DOM options. outerHTML is not a property of a bundle (array, object, etc). You need to select each option like a loop